# Use row or column features for CvStatModel train()?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

The [train()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-train) method allow to select CV_ROW_SAMPLE or CV_COL_SAMPLE to determine how the features are stored in the training data. Is there any advantage in using one or the other when training a model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some benchmarks with [CvBoost::train()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#cvboost-train) and the results indicate that using CV_COL_SAMPLE is at least 25% faster when using a low (less than 1k each) number of features/samples and up to 60% faster when using more features/samples.

So, althought I find it less intuitive, it is better to use CV_COL_SAMPLE to achieve equivalent models in less time. This could be different with other ML algorithms.